# are *.js files in node/lib used during compilation of the node executable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, embedded-v8

How are the files in [Node.js source code's lib directory](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib)  used by node? Does the node executable interpret the files in the library before running or are these javascript files some how used during compilation of the node executable?

Comment: These would be runtime libraries that you can include in your application (using `require`). They are not "pre-compiled".

Comment: They are the source code of the Node.js internal modules described in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those files are what are termed internal Javascript files.  They are packaged into the node executable and node.js knows how to get them from the executable when needed during the running of a node.js app.  Executable files contain a resource system so that in addition to code, they can also contain other types of resources (text, images, dialogs, etc...).

When you do `require()` in a node.js script file, it checks the name you're looking for against a list of known internal script filenames.  If it matches, then it fetches the source from its internal location in the executable file, not from a separate file in your local file system.  Similarly, if the `require()` is coming from within one of these internal files, it knows to look for the required file in its internal location too.

They are run as Javascript at the time of execution.  They are not precompiled into something other than Javascript.  The main difference is that they are Javascript script resources contained within the node executable, not something loaded from the file system.

Comment: "They are packaged into the node executable" .. my understanding is that an executable is just a binary file, so does that not mean that these .js files were compiled down at some point? 

"Javascript script resources contained within the node executable".. could you explain by what mechanism .js scripts are 'contained' in an executable?

Comment: @N.Parikh - Windows executables files contain code and can also contain resources (such as strings) and the code in the executable can access those resources upon demand.

Comment: I understand now. The .js module code is stored in its raw javascript form within the executable as data. I was able to confirm this using a hex editor to see the raw js source code embedded within the node binary. Thank youuu @jfriend00